# connecting to SQL Server 2000 in Netbeans?

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans

I have a SQL Server 2000 database on my local PC and I now want to connect to connect to it through Netbeans.  However, I can't seem to connect to the database. 
This is the error what I have.

[image]

Comment: Why did Yoy write MySql???

Comment: Do you have the JDBC drivers for SQL Server?  Have you installed them into Netbeans?

Comment: yes i have and i installed all the drivers.

Comment: What's unclear about "Invalid URL"? Which JDBC driver and version are you using? And why you are using a SQL Server version that is no longer supported?

Comment: Mssqlserver.jar, MsBase.jar, MsUtil.jar

Comment: i found some old program in my office. i need to connet that data base.

Comment: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23409790/Help-connecting-to-SQL-Server-2000-in-Netbeans.html

Comment: i followed above link and i did all the things in their. but i couldn't connect to the ms sql server 2000.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using NB 6.1? It is really outdated. We are at 8.2. Please update first, maybe it could be fix the problem. The other question is, is it really needed to use such an old SQL server?

I know that those questions are not that related to the original problem but to use such old technologies is dangerous because they will not maintained anymore and maybe there are still bugs inside.

Of course, if you really have to use those technologies than it is so.

Second is the SQL server already running?